# Need help finding out why this error occurs

Tags: java

My code is this:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
 import java.io.*;
 import javax.swing.Timer;

 public class chromeNPlayerScreen extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   DrawScreen dPnl = new DrawScreen(); 
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   }
   public void main(String[ ] args){
     this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     this.add(dPnl);
     this.setSize(600,600);;
     this.setVisible(true);
     this.setResizable(false);
     this.setLocation(200, 200);
   }  
 }
```

But when i run it.....

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Could someone explain to me why this isnt working?

the DrawScreen code is

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.URL;

public class DrawScreen extends JPanel {
  String picPath = "pictures/";
  ClassLoader cl = pokemonChromeNewPlayerScreen.class.getClassLoader();
  URL imgURL = cl.getResource(picPath+"welcomeBG.png"),imgURL2 = cl.getResource(picPath+"dialogBox.png"),
    imgURL3 = cl.getResource(picPath+"Professor.png");
  Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  Image imgBG, imgDialog, imgProfessor;

  public void imgImport(){
    imgBG = tk.createImage(imgURL);
    imgDialog = tk.createImage(imgURL2);
    imgProfessor = tk.createImage(imgURL3);
  }
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
      for(int x=0;x<=600;x+=25){
        g2.drawLine(x,0,x,600);
        g2.drawString(""+x,x+5,20);
      }
      for(int y=0;y<=600;y+=25){
        g2.drawLine(0,y,600,y);
        g2.drawString(" "+y,0,y+20);
      }
  }
}
```

This is the code for the DrawScreen, atm all it does it drag a grid but thats because i just started it and wanted the x,y values for different positions

Comment: A friend of mine is telling me that when the main() is called in java, the class has never been instantiated yet, thus any class members are going to be null. And since you aren't in a specific instance of an object, there is no 'this'.

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: it does compile, the error happens when i run it

Comment: @ Code-Guru sure ill edit the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is something related to your IDE.  Specifically, it's looking for a *non-static* version of `main()`.

This:

```
public void main(String[ ] args){

}
```

Should actually be:

```
public static void main(String[ ] args){

}
```

... of course, this means the `this` reference no longer works -  you'll need to actually create a `chromeNPlayerScreen` first:

```
public static void main(String[ ] args){
   chromeNPlayerScreen screen = new chromeNPlayerScreen();
   screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   screen.add(dPnl);
   screen.setSize(600,600);;
   screen.setVisible(true);
   screen.setResizable(false);
   screen.setLocation(200, 200);
}
```

Comment: This works but now i cant add dPnl, it says non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: well i just kind of did what you did and moved the declaration into the main and it worked, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void main(String[ ] args){
```

should be

```
public static void main(String[ ] args){
```

Without the appropriate `main`-method declaration there is no entry point for the JVM.

Having said this, it looks like the code currently in your 'main' should really be in a constructor of your class - and it looks like you probably meant to create an instance of your class in the `main`-method.

Comment: if i put static, it says
     "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @Exikle See the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: sorry, i do not understand what you mean? I dont really know the terms

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` method is currently not behaving as the entry method. It should be defined as `static` i.e.

```
  public static void main(String[ ] args){
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main is not static , replace  this:

```
public void main(String[] args)
```

by this :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```